# IIS7 APP pool recycling: what is the valid format for a schedule string?

Tags: iis-7, iis

I'm trying to specify an app pool recycling schedule to more than one specific time, but I'm receiving an error `invalid schedule string`.

What is the valid time format for a schedule string for app pool recycling in IIS7?

Comment: A good start would be telling us what you're currently trying and pasing scripts/config files. No one is going to be able to guess what's wrong with your config if we can't see your config.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't list how you're attempting to do this, I'll show you the easiest way. It can be configured through the IIS Manager GUI. Right click on the App Pool and select `Recycling` from the context menu. From there, you can set a comma separated list of times to recycle that app pool. There is a sample string right below the text field. The times should have a space between the value and AM or PM, but not before or after the comma that separates the values.

[image]